# rails production images assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a really weird production problem. In the invitation mail that I have a little personalized, I added 5 images, they are all stored in the assets/images folder but in different sub-folders.
I don't understand why, but the first three are displayed while the last two are not. In local and in the preview of the mail, everything works well.

```html
 <div id="body">
        <div id="logo-container">
          <%= image_tag("logo-trans-black.png", id: 'logo') %>
        </div>
        <div id="photo-container">
          <%= image_tag("mail/photo_link.jpg", id: 'photo') %>
        </div>
        <div class="container" >
          <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h3 id="hello">Bonjour <%= @resource.firstname %> ! </h3>
            <p class="msg">Votre entreprise <%= @resource.company.name %> vous invite à découvrir llalalalalallallalalalalalalalaalalalalal.</p>
            <p class="msg">Vous pouvez dès à présent vous inscrire et commencez à partager vos lalalalalalallalaalalalalalalalalallalaal.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="button-container">
            <p>
              <%= link_to accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @token) do %>
                <%= image_tag("mail/sign_in_button_link.jpg", id: 'sign-in') %>
              <% end %>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
          <div id="social-nw">
            <%= image_tag("png/social-n/facebook-logo.png", id: 'facebook') %>
            <%= image_tag("png/social-n/linkedin-logo.png", id: 'linkedin') %>
          </div>
          <div id="address">
            <p>
              Lalalala <br> lalal <br> 1lalalalalal
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="condition">
            <p>
              Vous recevez cet email en accord avec votre société qui nous a transmis votre adresse email.
              Pour accéder aux conditions de confidentialité des lalalaalalalal
              Si vous ne souhaitez plus recevoir d'emails de notre part, cliquez ici.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem was that my host assets was the production address while I was doing my tests on the stagging application so all the images were not available.

Thanks anyway